# xlwings: Selecting non-adjacent columns

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

How would one go about selecting non-adjacent columns using xlwings in python?

I'm not sure if this thought is either too simple, or out of scope of what xlwings natively provides, but it seems like it would be a straightforward task and normal thing to do when working with spreadsheets.  Conceptually it would be something like `xw.Range('A1,C1,F1').expand('down')` where I want the row-aligned information in each of those columns with any blank cells being type-padded with `None` as xlwings does by default in ranges.

[image: Example Data screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can select non adjacent ranges:

```
import xlwings
wb = xw.Book()
sheet = wb.sheets("Sheet1")
sht.range(sht.range("A1,C1,F1")).select()
```